# Document Preview in Search Result, SharePoint 2013 is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, fast-search, sharepoint-search

I performed below steps.

1. Created a web application
2. Created a separate enterprise search site collection.
3. Created Search Service Application.
4. Created content source

Now, the search is working fine. But I cannot get the document preview.
[image: My Search Result]

My Desired Output is shown below, (with the given document preview)
[image: Desired Output]

Do we need to have a Separate office web app server for document preview in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you need Office Web Apps to enable Document Preview.
And Yes that needs a separate server/farm.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Per's answer: Here is my instruction how to install it:
http://melcher.it/2013/05/install-office-web-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-2013-with-pdf-preview/

Follow the reference to Wictor Willens blog for the basic instruction and use my powershell to enable PDF preview.

Comment: This addition should be a comment on Anders answer, not a separate answer IMO

Comment: Robert, you are right. "Answered" on my mobile and hit the wrong button.

Comment: Good input though :)

Answer (score 1):

I just faced a similar problem.

Using a custom display template might not give you the preview features.
Resolved it by changing the display template settings to the one that says

```
"Use the result type to decide"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this : 
[View docs after owa install in search results](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28574.sharepoint-2013-owa-previews-not-displaying-in-search-results.aspx)

Comment: Please add a description of the proposed resolution to your answer. Link-only answers become less useful over time as links tend to break.